# How do I change the underline of a material ui tab

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to change the underline of:

[image]

I use material ui version 4.12.3

The code for creating my tabs is here:

```
function renderTabs(): JSX.Element {
return (
  <Tabs className={classes.tabBar} value={activeTab} component={Paper} onChange={handleChange} centered>
    {TABS.map((tab: string) => {
      return (
        <Tab
          className={classes.tabButton}
          key={`tab-${tab}`}
          label={tab}
          value={tab}
          component={Link}
          to={`${url}/${tab !== TABS[0] ? tab : ''}`}
        />
      )
    })}
  </Tabs>
)
```

}

and in my tab_menu.style.ts I have the following code:

```
export default makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    root: { width: '60%', margin: 'auto' },
    tabBar: {},
    tabButton: {},
  })
)
```

I tried to change colors/background colors/text decorations in the tabBar as well as the tabButton, but the blue underline never changed.
How can I change the underline style?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this sx prop to my tabs solves my problem of underlining.

```
sx={{ "& .MuiTabs-indicator": { display: "none" } }}

    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>

      <Tabs
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      aria-label="nav tabs example"
      role="navigation"
      sx={{ "& .MuiTabs-indicator": { display: "none" } }}
      >
        <LinkTab label="Page One" href="/drafts" />
        <LinkTab label="Page Two" href="/trash" />
        <LinkTab label="Page Three" href="/spam" />
      </Tabs>

    </Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per material-UI documentation ([Tab API](https://v4.mui.com/api/tab/),  [Tabs API](https://v4.mui.com/api/tabs/)) , you need to pass `classes` instead of `className` as a prop. Just write `classes` instead `className`.

Comment: I used classes instead of className and I read through the documentation. But nothing helps for the underline to be changed. :(

Comment: I hope [this article](https://smartdevpreneur.com/how-to-style-material-ui-tabs-and-tab-indicator-plus-typescript/) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Foolproof  Snippet**

```
const MyTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tabs
      TabIndicatorProps={{
        style: {
          display: 'none'
        }
      }}
    >
      <Tab label="Tab 1" />
      <Tab label="Tab 2" />
      <Tab label="Tab 3" />
    </Tabs>
  );
};
```

**Your SCSS goes here**

```
.MuiTabs-root {
  .MuiTabs-fixed {
    .MuiTabs-flexContainer {
      .MuiButtonBase-root {
        // add styles for the tab buttons here
      }

      &.Mui-selected {
        span {
          border-bottom: 3px solid red;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```